# Javascript - where to find/propose new methods?

Tags: javascript, standards, forward-compatibility

Say someone has an idea for a new, very useful and cool method, for instance `String.prototype.multiply`. She does not see it in current javascript implementations. But maybe it's already implemented in some javascript/ajax libraries or maybe similar method (with a different name, but she does not know) is current de-facto standard or even is on its way to some future ECMAScript version already..

Her aim is to implement the new functionality in her js code right, with compatibility with newer javascript or 3rd party code in mind (she does not necessarily want to propose a new standard).

What is the best place to find it out / discuss?

Comment: @epascarello this was just an example.. i don't know, maybe she wants `'xxx'` instead of `NaN`, when she does `'x' * 3`, like in python. er, i mean, when she does `'x'.multiply(3)`

Comment: Love how you talk about yourself in 3rd person. lol :)

Comment: @epascarello wrong. i want to implement completely different method. and there are more differences.

Comment: See the [ES Harmony Proposals](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proposals), BTW the [`String.prototype.repeat`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:string.prototype.repeat) method has already been proposed. Check also the [es-discuss mailing list](https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/es-discuss).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say Google and SO to find it. To propose/discuss, head over to ECMAScript site's community: http://www.ecmascript.org/dev.php